# How do i update CI session without destroying it

Tags: php, codeigniter, session

```
    //setting session data
    $loginData = array(
      'name'  => 'Rajeev Singh',
      'email' => 'rajeev@gmail.com',
      'age'   => '21',
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata('loginData',$loginData);

//accessing session data
$name = $this->session->userdata('loginData')['name'];
```

suppose if my users want to update his/her details then I need to change in session
but I'm unable to update session value

currently what I'm doing is creating a whole new session which changes my session ID
I wanted to update one value of my session without changing session ID

```
//accessing session ID
$sessionID =  $this->session->session_id;
```

Comment: if you need the same ID, why not set a value for 'user_id'=>12345, because session will renew at each page load, so a F5 will produce a new session_ID as well

Comment: Have you tried using `$this->session->userdata('loginData')['name'] = $new-name;` or `$this->session->set_userdata('loginData['name']', $new-name);`?

Comment: Yes, Brother, I am tried all of these but not working any of these options.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r($_SESSION["logindata"]); 

$_SESSION["logindata"]["name"]="updated name";

print_r($_SESSION["logindata"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will update your session variable 'loginData' using Codeigniter without destroying the session.

I'm using `$data_update` where your custom variable would go.

`$this->session->set_userdata('loginData', $data_update)`;

Codeigniter Sessions page
[1] http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Answer (score 0):

Just overwrite the sessions

```
//initial set
loginData = array(
      'name'  => 'Rajeev Singh',
      'email' => 'rajeev@gmail.com',
      'age'   => '21',
    );

$this->session->set_userdata('loginData', $loginData);

//overwritting

$loginData = array(
      'name'  => 'new name',
      'email' => 'new email',
      'age'   => 'new age',
    );
$this->session->set_userdata('loginData', $loginData);
```

Take look at [here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/sessions.html#adding-session-data).